# How to add Bar Code Sanning feature to xamarin forms IOS app using Zxing.Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, xamarin, zxing

I need to add scanning functionality to an existing mobile application. The application will be scanning a bar code using zxing.mobile package.

Comment: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile.forms

Answer (score 0):

```
for xamarin forms
var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage ();
// Navigate to our scanner page
await Navigation.PushAsync (scanPage);



scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => 
{
    // Stop scanning
    scanPage.IsScanning = false;

    // Pop the page and show the result
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => 
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync ();        
        await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
    });
};


Documenation is here in this link
https://blog.xamarin.com/barcode-scanning-made-easy-with-zxing-net-for-xamarin-forms/
```